# on the properties of semidirect product of finite groups

Tags: semidirect-product

If $G$ is a finite group such that $G/H \cong K$, where $H,K \leq G$, then is it true that $G \cong H \rtimes K$?
it is sufficient to show that $H \cap K=1$ and $G=HK$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it isn't. For example with the quaternion group

$$\mathcal Q_8=\{1,-1,i,j,k,-i,-j,-k\}\;,\;\;\mathcal Q_8/\langle i\rangle\cong\{1,-1\}\require{cancel} \cancel{\implies}\mathcal Q_8\cong \langle i\rangle\rtimes\langle -1\rangle$$

because, of course, $\;\langle -1\rangle\subset\langle i\rangle\;$ ... In fact, the subgroup of order two in this case is unique (and thus normal), and it is contained in any other non-trivial subgroup of $\;\mathcal Q_8\;$ .

Comment: Thanks a lot. can we put a condition on $G$ or $H$ or $K$ to hold?

Comment: @Hana Well, to begin with we must have $\;H\cap K=1\;$ ...and that's all, since the condition $\;G/H\cong K\;$ already says $\;H\lhd G\;$ and that's all we need.

Comment: Ok thak you very much dear DonAntonio